# Where I can get "Nikah" to enter second marriage in UK?

Tags: nikah

My name is Danyal. I converted to Islam in Istanbul in 2015, but live in Scotland, Lanark since 2014 (before that in England-5 years). My nationality is, "Polish", but soon "British" (in a few months). I am  husband of one wife. She is Jewish only through the way of her thinking. Her Jewish status has not been performed in synagogue, which means by the Polish standards she is "Catholic", but gave them letter of apostasy. I am married to her through "civil contract"-legal in Poland and respected in EU.

Lately I have met Saudi Arab girl, she lives in Jeddah, for now. My wife agreed me to enter another marriage. But of course there is no legal way to do that in UK-by the UK standards, because according to UK standards it would be "bigamy".

That is why question is, if my potential "second wife/next wife" can be married to me through "Nikah" ceremony only. We are aware  the Nikah ceremony has no legal attachment to Law in UK, which means my next wife will not be recognized as a wife. Nevertheless, she wants "Nikah" ceremony, for the religious purpose and in the eyes of Allah to be my wife (next wife). All practical issues have been discussed between us. Can you give me any decent legal Mosque address who perform "Nikah" ceremony of second marriage?

I look forward to hearing from you
Yours faithfully 
Danyal C

Comment: It's better illustrate your question more clearly. SO Long Question it is!!

Comment: Uh yeah, it looks a little long which makes many users ignore it ... Then you'd better a little make your nice answer shorter ... / Good luck